# Using @Autowired in the spring main application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a spring project and in here I implement the command line runner as the application I create need to be run on the console. So inside the run method I created an object of another class and called the method for executing the application.

So when creating the object I had to make it Autowired and the relevant class a Component.
Is it a good coding way to do code or is there any other way to avoid the null pointer exception.

And my knowledge on why I put the Autowired is not 100% certain, I think Autowired keyword injects the beans of the class Menu so the methods and variables of that class can be called. Is it correct ?

**Main Class**

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Menu obj;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        obj.start();
    }
    }
```

**Menu Class**

```
    @Component
    public class Menu {
        
        public void start(){
            //implementation 
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no issues and seems fine. Are you facing any issues?

Comment: No there is no issue it works fine, I just need to know what I've done is correct and if it's a good coding way.

Comment: Yes, it is one good way to manage dependencies in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this much better

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication, args);

        context.getBean(Menu).start(); // <-- here
    }
}
```

Hope useful

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **@PostConstruct** **annotation** over a method instead of **command line runner** to execute code after running the application.

example:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
   obj.start();
// or any code that use @autowired injection
}
```